# Throw error on invalid lookup in Talend job that populates an output table

Tags: talend

I have a tMap component in a Talend job. The objective is to get a row from an input table, perform a column lookup in another input table, and write an output table populating one of the columns with the retrieved value (see screenshot below).

If the lookup is unsuccessful, I generate a row in an "invalid rows" table. This works fine however is not the solution I'm looking for.

Instead, I want to stop the entire process and throw an error on the first unsuccessful lookup. Is this possible in Talend? The error that is thrown should contain the value that failed the lookup.

[image]

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: I guess a tfileoutputdelimited would do the staff . So , after tMap ->invalid_row->tfileoutputdelimited -> tdie  . Note : that you have to go to advanced settings in the tfileoutputdelimited  component  aand tick 
split output into multiple files option and put 1 rather then 1000

Comment: It worked perfectly. Now the issue is that if I want to join two tables (or more) and have one tfileoutputdelimited for each table that is joined, the first tfileoutputdelimited will catch `any` inner join reject, not only of the join of table that is mapped, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Could you edit your post with the solution  i mentionned and tell me what you are looking to reach or failure that you have occured so i can help ?

Comment: Because for me , you can do the query using inner join and put it to a tdbinput then catch the reject directly without doing a tmap i guess ! so it's more preferable that you edit the question so that i can help

Comment: Please see update. The problem is that I have two `catch lookup inner join reject` but always the first one is triggered regardless of the join that failed.

Comment: Okey ! simply do two tmap order than one tMap

Comment: Perfect! it worked, I owe you dinner

Comment: Perfect ! Could you mark the topic as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `tfileoutputdelimited`   componenent would do the staff .

So ,the  flow would be as such `tMap ->invalid_row->tfileoutputdelimited -> tdie`

**Note :** that you have to go to advanced settings in the `tfileoutputdelimited`  component aand tick `split output into multiple files option`  and put `1`  rather then `1000`

**For more flexibility** , `simply do two tmap order than one tMap`